# Navigate to another sheet from comboBox Value

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
        ComboBox1.Value = ""
    Else
        ComboBox1.Value = Left(ComboBox1.Value, Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(" - ", ComboBox1.Value) - 1)

        Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Select
        ComboBox1.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() 
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=NO_NAMA_FAIL1"
    ComboBox1.Value = ""
End Sub
```

This is my code above.
The list value from the comboBox are originally in this format:

```
PNS.100-1|3|2 JLD.1 - PELANTIKAN GUAMAN
```

then I removed the text after `" - "` because the sheetname are only `PNS.100-1|3|2 JLD.1` this part.

I successfully remove the text after `" - "` as its show on the comboBox after I selected it but it doesn't go to the sheet that I selected, I'm not sure as to why is that, can anyone help me.

[myCodePic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5P6Y.png)

Comment: `it doesn't go to the sheet that I selected` - what happens instead?

Comment: nothing happen, it just show this PNS.100-1|3|2 JLD.1 on the comboBox

Comment: Are you sure you have an actual ActiveX control named ComboBox1, as opposed to a form control? Do you have `ComboBox1` in the left dropdown of the code pane window?

Comment: I do, it is a activeX ComboBox1, I added a picture for you to verify

Comment: On the line where you set `ComboBox1.Value`, `ComboBox1_Change` fires again (because you have just changed the value of the combobox). Having fired again, with the already-truncated value, it will try to find a `" - "` in that again, and will fail. At this point a runtime error will occur (1004 - Unable to get the Search property of the WorksheetFunction class), and because you are not seeing it, this cannot be the code you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @GSerg regarding the error. I was able to re-create the error he posted.

[image]

I just copied your code, created a named ranged to be used for filling the values and created the sheet named as you described and the error occurred. So I am also curious what code you're actually running.

To answer your question though, do not change the value of the `ComboBox`. Instead, use a variable to store your actual sheet name and use that on the `Select` method.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Dim sName As String
  
  With Me
    If .ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
      'better to just do nothing
    Else
      sName = Left(.ComboBox1.Value, _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(" - ", .ComboBox1.Value) - 1)
      Sheets(sName).Select
      .ComboBox1.Value = ""
    End If
  End With
  
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

  With Me
    .ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=NO_NAMA_FAIL1"
    .ComboBox1.Value = ""
  End With
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Was going to suggest using `Application.EnableEvents = False` but that'd prevent a plausible Worksheet_Activate on the other sheet and I apparently forgot the ComboBox1_Change didn't count as an event :') +1

Comment: Thankyou everyone my problem are solved, I myself not sure as to why I didnt get the error, I tried your @L42 suggestion and it work thankyou :)